# python - How to handle "old" dates when transfering data to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

I have the dataframe where one of the columns contains date strings. I first convert it to datetime with:

```
mydf['Desk Date'] = pd.to_datetime(mydf['Desk Date'])`
```

and then drop the dataframe to excel with

```
Range('A1').value = mydf`
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-111-6c6f5ea1ff17>", line 1, in <module>
Import.ImportFWD(test_path)
File "C:\Users\jastrzem\Downloads\pyWFP\Import.py", line 42, in ImportFWD
Range('A1').value = mydf
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 818, in value
self.row1, self.col1, row2, col2), data)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 151, in set_value
xl_range.Value = data
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 560, in __setattr__
self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

One of the dates is `Timestamp('1899-01-31 00:00:00')`
which I think is the reason for the error.

I tried to use `np.where` to substitute all values before year 2000 to `NaN`, but with no luck.

```
f = lambda x: x.year
mydf['Desk Date'] = np.where(pd.DataFrame(mydf['Desk Date']).applymap(f) > 2000, pd.to_datetime(mydf['Desk Date'], format='%D/%M/%Y'),np.nan)
```

How can I fix the above command or alternatively how should I handle dates that are "not transferable" to excel?

Thanks!

**[EDIT]:**
I tried to use `to_excel` method but with no luck either. The code I put at the end of my function:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test7.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
mydf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
writer.close()
```

it creates the file but it's empty. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-26-6c6f5ea1ff17>", line 1, in <module>
Import.ImportFWD(test_path)
File "C:\Users\jastrzem\Downloads\pyWFP\Import.py", line 44, in ImportFWD
writer.close()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 623, in close
return self.save()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1298, in save
return self.book.close()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 295, in close
self._store_workbook()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 518, in _store_workbook
xml_files = packager._create_package()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 140, in _create_package
self._write_shared_strings_file()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 280, in _write_shared_strings_file
sst._assemble_xml_file()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\sharedstrings.py", line 53, in _assemble_xml_file
self._write_sst_strings()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\sharedstrings.py", line 83, in _write_sst_strings
self._write_si(string)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\sharedstrings.py", line 110, in _write_si
self._xml_si_element(string, attributes)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\xmlwriter.py", line 122, in _xml_si_element
self.fh.write("""<si><t%s>%s</t></si>""" % (attr, string))
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\codecs.py", line 694, in write
return self.writer.write(data)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python271\lib\codecs.py", line 357, in write
data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Use the `to_excel` method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel will not accept dates before 1900. My workaround is to replace "old" dates with np.nan since I know they are data errors anyway.

```
mydf['Desk Date'] = pd.to_datetime(mydf['Desk Date'])
dates_list = list(mydf['Desk Date'])
dates_list = [x if x.year > 1900 else np.nan for x in dates_list ]
mydf['Desk Date'] = dates_list
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is not because of the old date, but because you are trying to throw a whole dataframe at a single cell.

Instead, use the [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method.

Comment: This is not the reason. I forgot to mention I'm using `from xlwings import Workbook, Range`. When I don't manipulate the date column and leave it as string everything works fine. Excel opens and a dataframe is pasted into cell A1. However when I add only this bit: `mydf['Desk Date'] = pd.to_datetime(mydf['Desk Date'])` it returns an error. Actually the workbook opens, it populates some cells down to line 385 where the first "old date" is found and then it returns an error, so I'm 99,99% sure it's about the date