# Excel date cells generate a random bug with ExcelJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, typescript, exceljs

I'm encountering an issue while parsing an Excel file using ExcelJS in a Node.js environment. The Excel file contains cells representing dates, but it seems that some of these cells are being treated as strings, while others are correctly converted to actual date objects. Despite trying various approaches, I haven't been able to resolve this issue.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
export default async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

  if (!req.files?.length) {
    res.send("Files not found");
    return;
  }

  try {
    // @ts-ignore
    await workbook.xlsx.load(req.files[0].buffer);

    const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);

    if (worksheet?.actualColumnCount != EXCEL_COLUMN_NUMBER) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        user_message:
          "Not correct number of column",
      });
    }
    worksheet.spliceRows(1, 1);

    worksheet?.eachRow(async (row, rowIndex) => {
      const rowCellValue = row.values as CellValue[]
      console.log("Birthdate :", rowCellValue[ExcelColumns.BirthDate];
});
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error processing Excel file:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Error processing Excel file");
  }
```

Excel column:
[image]

Output:
[image]

I desire to ensure that all cells in the Excel file have a unique type (either text or date) so that I can parse them accurately. While I acknowledge that checking the type is a viable solution, I am reluctant to accept it as the sole approach.

I attempted to address this issue by creating a parsing function, but it fails due to the incorrect expected type:

```
export function parseStringToDate(dateString: string): Date | null {
  const formats = [
    { format: "DD/MM/YYYY", separator: "/" },
    { format: "MM/YYYY", separator: "/" },
    { format: "YYYY", separator: "/" },
  ];

  for (const { format, separator } of formats) {
    const tokens = format.split("/");
    const dateParts = dateString.split(separator);

    if (dateParts.length === tokens.length) {
      const dateValues: any = {};

      for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        const token = tokens[i];
        const part = dateParts[i];

        if (!isNaN(parseInt(part, 10))) {
          dateValues[token] = parseInt(part, 10);
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }

      const year = dateValues["YYYY"];
      const month = dateValues["MM"] || 1;
      const day = dateValues["DD"] || 1;

      if (month < 1 || month > 12 || day < 1 || day > 31) {
        return null;
      }

      return new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Please help :((

Comment: So your problem is white color of print (Wrong as string), purple color of print(correct as Data/time) so you want to white color of print as handling as same as purple rows?

Comment: Looks like Excel will not accept dates before 1900, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047526/python-how-to-handle-old-dates-when-transfering-data-to-excel/37116189#37116189) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093573/calculations-in-excel-spreadsheet-using-pre-1900-date). Also, note that there was an Excel bug that treated 1900 as a leap year, there are some threads about it, for example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335478/vba-excel-did-i-find-a-bug-with-how-excel-handles-the-leap-year-in-1900-it).